# Reduce Java heap Memory

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wrongly increased the heap size of my android studio, and when i start android studio , i am getting this error

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I know this is something related to Java heap memory, i have reinstalled the  Android studio, but getting the same error.

Please tell me where can i change the heap size of Java ?? i am using ubuntu18

Comment: How did you increase the `Xmx` value? Look in `<install-path>/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions` and `<install-path>/android-studio/bin/studio.vmoptions`, `$HOME/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions`.

Comment: You wrongly increases the heap size, you write ... then decrease it the same place.

Comment: @Thomas - it was at this location $HOME/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions you can mark it answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start script `<install-path>/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` does consult the files as follows to read configurations.

---

For 64bit systems:

```
<install-path>/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions
${HOME}/.AndroidStudio<version>/config/studio64.vmoptions
<install-path>/android-studio.vmoptions
```

---

For 32bit systems:

```
<install-path>/android-studio/bin/studio.vmoptions
${HOME}/.AndroidStudio<version>/config/studio.vmoptions
<install-path>/android-studio.vmoptions
```

---

Depending on your architecture 32bit vs 64bit and how you did change the heap size setting, you can look through the files mentioned above and alter the `Xmx` with a text editor of your choice.